# Intellij IDEA 2017.2 can't add openjk 9 on Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, java, java-9, intellij-idea2017

I am using **Intellij IDEA** *2017.2.5* on *Linux Mint 18.2* and trying to add new openjdk-9 **SDK** but IDEA does not accept openjdk 9 as valid JDK:

[image: Intellij claims about SDK home]

I have installed all of my SDKs using apt-get from ppa standard repositories.
This is my `update-alternatives --config java/javac` output:

[image: update-alternatives --config java/javac]

Although Intellij declared it would support *JDK 9* [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/07/support-for-java-9-in-intellij-idea-2017-2/), but it seems it is not yet fully compatible with at least opensdk-9.
Maybe refactoring SDK directory and removing '**jre**' folder misleads the IDEA to find the SDK 9 home folder.

Any idea why Intellij IDEA claims '**The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK**' ?

Comment: Looks like it's not the latest build.  IDEA does not support builds earlier than b164. Please download a recent one from http://jdk.java.net/9/.

Comment: Thanks a lot @y.bedrov . I did not know about this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[“ Ubuntu PPA for OpenJDK”](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) currently has very old build of openjdk-9(**9~b115-1ubuntu1**).
So the IDEA does not recognize it as a valid SDK.
I removed current installed version:

`sudo apt-get remove '^openjdk-9.*'`

Then I have downloaded newer .deb build(9~b181) files including jre,jre-headless,... from [launchpad build archive](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-9/9~b181-4/+build/13293267).

```
sudo dpkg -i openjdk-9-jre-headless_9_b181-4_amd64.deb  
             openjdk-9-jre_9_b181-4_amd64.deb 
             openjdk-9-jdk-headless_9_b181-4_amd64.deb 
             openjdk-9-jdk_9_b181-4_amd64.deb
```

Just Execute the above command at a single line, line breaks are for better readability.

Ignore any error complaining about:

> "Package libpng16-16 is not installed."

Next execute the following:

```
  sudo apt-get install -f
```

Now after installing this build of openjdk-9 the IDEA is happy with SDK home.

Thanks [@y.bedrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2960034/y-bedrov) for his useful comment.

**Update:**
However this solution enables you to declare openjdk-9 in the mentioned IDEA version(2017-2) but you are not able to compile any class within the IDEA itself.
You can only compile your application with elder jdk and run it with openjdk-9. There is an other issue which indicates this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357211/openjdk-9-intellij-idea-ubuntu-cant-resolve-symbol).

In the newer IDEA versions(I have tested 2017.3) this build of openjdk is not allowed to be used as new SDK any more, see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296429/properly-set-up-java-9-as-sdk-in-intellij-idea-on-linux-due-to-new-folder-struct).

The short reason is an issue in Debian package which contains incorrectly compiled lib/jrt-fs.jar file.

[See this Answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850159/732328)