# OpenJDK 9 IntelliJ IDEA (Ubuntu) "Can't resolve Symbol"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, java

I recently installed openJDK 9 under Ubuntu 17.10 and it seems like IntelliJ IDEA has trouble with it.

Whenever I create a new project IntelliJ can find the JDK, but it seems like it's not configuring it the right way. Here is how it looks like

[image: Project Structure]

when I create a HelloWorld.java example it looks like this

[image: HelloWorld]

and it says 'Can't resolve symbol 'String''.

Everything works fine when I compile via terminal and even with Eclipse.

When I type 'java --version' it says

> openjdk 9-Ubuntu
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4, mixed mode)

**Is there a way to fix this problem?**

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu but "/usr/bin/jvm" seems wrong.  Look for a different directory, maybe just under "/usr/bin/" ("/usr/bin/java" for example).

Comment: Can you verify the path to your JDK home is valid i.e. inspect the directory manually?

Comment: Also perhaps check with `update-alternatives --config java`.

Comment: Related thread already open for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296429/how-to-properlly-setup-jdk9-as-sdk-in-intellij-idea-on-linux-due-to-new-folder-s

Comment: @Kerry I checked the path manually and it’s correct. I’ll try openjdk 8 and see if it’s working. I used to have oracle jdk which worked fine but after setting up a fresh install of ubuntu 17.10 I wanted to try openjdk.

Comment: @jslr Agreed. But ideally this/that shall get closed as a dupe. Its better to upvote an existing question if you are about to ask the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to Debian packaging of openjdk-9 in the **lib/jrt-fs.jar** file. This file is compiled incorrectly.
This bug is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-9/+bug/1727002) and there is a more complete [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850159/732328).

If you insist to make use of openjdk you might wait for the new versions or try to build it from the source using the recommended options on the launchpad.